# Unable to use datediff function in Apache OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc, date

I am unable to get a result by using the command `=DATEDIFF('dd', '2007-08-01', '2007-09-01')` in Apache OpenOffice Calc.

Even using two columns of dates and using the formula `=DATEDIFF('dd','A2','B2')`, I am unable to find the difference between dates.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

DATEDIFF seems to be OpenOffice Base/SQL function, not Calc function. It can be used in Calc as Basic macro custom function.

Answer (score 1):

The "Day" calculation from NANANG above is incorrect. Here is a correction

Microsoft Excel use  DATEDIFF function which Apache do not have
=DATEDIFF(A4;TODAY();"y")&" years, "&DATEDIFF(A4;TODAY();"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIFF(A4;TODAY();"md")&" days"

Apache Office do it this way, "Day" calculated with 30.42 days/month 365/12=30.42 then ROUND it to 1 decimal place.

=YEARS(A4;NOW();0)&" Years, "&((MONTHS(A4;NOW();0))-(YEARS(A4;NOW();0)*12))&" Months, "&(ROUND(MOD(MOD(ROUND((DAYS(NOW();$A$4)));365);30.42);1)&" Days")

A4 cell contain the start date

Answer (score 0):

There's no function named DATEDIFF available from the [OpenOffice Calc Date & Time funstions](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Date_&_Time_functions).

Instead, you should use the Calc-specific funtions, for example the [`DAYS`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_DAYS_function) function to calculate the number of days between two dates:

```
=DAYS("2007-08-01", "2007-09-01")
```

**EDIT:** Regarding DATEDIFF: this is a function that's part of the Core SQL:1999 standard (see the [overview of date/time sql functions in the SQL Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/Date_and_time_functions)), so you can use it with most SQL databases (OpenOffice Base, MySQL, PostgreSQL and so on). But you can't use a SQL function natively in Calc.

Comment: I think there should be double quotes around the dates in your example.

Comment: @PleaseStand: thank you for the hint, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

=YEARS(C6;$C$3;0)&" Years, "&((MONTHS(C6;$C$3;0))-(YEARS(C6;$C$3;0)*12))&" Month,  "&(ROUNDDOWN((DAYS($C$3;C6))-(YEARS(C6;$C$3;0)*365)-(((MONTHS(C6;$C$3;0))-(YEARS(C6;$C$3;0)*12))*30);0)&" Day")

Note: $C$3 can be replace by =Now()

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain how this works?  Thanks.